# importable CAD-format with material Information

Tags: import, file-format

I model a lot in Fusion360, because it is easy to use and offers workflow. However, it does not allow to export as .dae. It *does* offer the following: .dwg .dxf .fbx .igs/.iges .obj .sat .skp .smt .stp .step .stl as well as the Autodesk formats for Fusion (.f3d) and Investor (.ipt).

I know Blender can import .stl and .obj, but both of these do not support to carry over any surface/material information that I had assigned to a model in Fusion.

Is any of the other formats a) importable into blender and b) transfers a chosen material information for parts of a surface?

Comment: Not clear what material information is meant in the question. Usually export formats are used to transfer material assignments. Materials themselves are recconstructed then in the end app. FBX and OBJ can do that

Comment: @MrZak Fusion360 defines objects as having a material (e.g. steel, rubber etc) and surfaces can be assigned a different material - I am not sure if that is "in application" only or something that they can and do import into obj - though obj in its native shape is not able to carry color information....

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures